# What's the best way to insert multiple rows into a mysql database using php?

Tags: php, mysql

The php code below get's the results from a form and inserts them into a table.

I have to used this table structure where each row corresponds to a different value from the form eg First Name.

I've written the code below but it's cumbersome.
Can you help me with a better way? Thanks heaps!

```
$lists      = $_POST['form']['lists'][0];
$first_name = $_POST['form']['first_name'];
$last_name  = $_POST['form']['last_name'];
$idu        = $db->insertid();

$db->setQuery("INSERT INTO #__rsmail_subscriber_details (`IdList`, `FieldName`, 
`FieldValue`, `IdSubscriber`) VALUES ('" . $db->getEscaped($lists) . "', 'First Name'
, '" . $db->getEscaped($first_name) . "', '" . $db->getEscaped($idu) . "')");

$db->query();

$db->setQuery("INSERT INTO #__rsmail_subscriber_details (`IdList`, `FieldName`, 
`FieldValue`, `IdSubscriber`) VALUES ('" . $db->getEscaped($lists) . "', 'Last Name'
, '" . $db->getEscaped($last_name) . "', '" . $db->getEscaped($idu) . "')");

$db->query();
```

Comment: Just curious - why are `setQuery` and `query` separated into 2 functions

Comment: My guess: http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_use_the_database_classes_in_your_script#setQuery.28.24query.29

Comment: Thanks heaps for the answer zerkms! Works great. I've just copied in the code from another site. How do I combine setQuery and query?

Comment: Did I just ask the most stupid question of the day?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can perform bulk insert:

```
INSERT INTO table (field1, field2) VALUES ('val1', 'val2'), ('val3', 'val4'), ...
```

In your case it is something like:

```
$db->setQuery("INSERT INTO #__rsmail_subscriber_details (`IdList`, `FieldName`, 
`FieldValue`, `IdSubscriber`) VALUES ('".$db->getEscaped($lists)."', 'First Name'
, '".$db->getEscaped($first_name)."', '".$db->getEscaped($idu)."'), ('".$db->getEscaped($lists)."', 'Last Name'
, '".$db->getEscaped($last_name)."', '".$db->getEscaped($idu)."')");
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your SQL question:

```
INSERT INTO `table` (foo, bar)
         VALUES (1, 2),
                (3, 4),
                (5, 6),
                (7, 8)
```

In regards to your PHP code, burn it and start over. It reeks of security issues and bad practices.

Comment: Uhm, which *security* issues?

Comment: @StackOverflowNewbie: XSS has nothing to do with databases.

Comment: Obvious direct DB insertion with $_POST data? You need to escape and bind variable if you are going to directly pipe it into the database in such manner.

Comment: @Aleksey Korzun: where do you see **direct** insertion?? He sanitized the data with `$db->getEscaped()` method, didn't he. And you're a little wrong, he need **either** escape **or** bind variables into a prepared statement.

Comment: Because we all know that if you use framework's escape methods you will never get exploited. There is no chance of mistakes in current or future revisions of the frame work. There is no chance of middle man attack overwriting that method within the package. And we also know that prepared statements are never needed if you already escaping $_POST data. /sarcasm.